# Reading fully from file descriptor of unknown size

Tags: c, pipe

I have used pipe and I have to read from this pipe. But problem is this:

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)
```

I don't know how many characters is stored in the reading end of pipe, so I can't assign some number to **count**. I need this to store in  the buffer.

How can I number of characters stored in this pipe?

With regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know how many characters is stored in the reading end of pipe

Don't worry about it.  There are advantages (e.g. atomicity) to not trying to write/read more than PIPE_BUF bytes at shot.  In reality you will probably get a bunch of short reads anyway.

```
#define READ_BUFFER_SIZE PIPE_BUF

unsigned char mybuffer[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];

ssize_t bytesread = 1;

while ((bytesread = read(pipefd, mybuffer, READ_BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
{
    concat to bigger buffer, realloc if necessary
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a reasonably sized buffer, and read as much as you can. Repeat that. The function returns the number of bytes read.

Comment: I used it but my program will be tested, for example if I use cat on file, it can be more larger than my assumption

Comment: Which is why you read a block, process it and then repeat it.

Comment: If you try to read it all for processing in one go, take a look at `realloc()`. Still, you might run out of space too fast.

Comment: that's where the `while` loop will kick in. It will keep reading until there are more bytes to be read.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply request the number of characters up to the size of your buffer, and do so repeatedly in a loop, e.g:

```
char* buf = malloc(1024);
do {
   bytes_read = read(fd, buf, 1024);
   // store buf somewhere else so you can use it in the next iteration
} while (bytes_read > 0)
free(buf);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not know before hand how many bytes are there and pass that as as a value for count.
You can define buffer of maximum data size that you can expect and read from the fd until data is present.

```
char buf[MAX_DATA_SIZE] = {0};

bytes_read = 0;
while(n > 0)
{
    n = read(fd,buf+bytes_read,MAX_DATA_SIZE)
    bytes_read = bytes_read + n;
}
```

Comment: +1, but don't forget to check that you don't overflow `buf`.  You need the third argument to be `MAX_DATA_SIZE - bytes_read`.  You should also test `n` before you add it, in case you get a failure (`n == -1`) which reduces the number of bytes read.  The standard C idiom would be `while ((n = read(fd, buf_bytes_read, MAX_DATA_SIZE - bytes_read)) > 0) bytes_read += n;` which tests `n` before you use it.